# Python pandas: Multicolumn dataframe - Shift one column without changing the other

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Supposing I have the following dataframe:

```
df = 

Index Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
0     10   20   30   40
1     11   21   31   41
2     12   22   32   42
3     13   23   33   43
```

Is there a pandas function or a simple way (without creating a duplicate .copy() dataframe) that will allow me to return the same dataframe but with one or more columns (e.g. Col2 & Col3) shifted by one row i.e .shift(1) without overwriting it?

In other words to get the following

```
df = 

Index Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
0     10   nan  nan  40
1     11   20   30   41
2     12   21   31   42
3     13   22   32   43
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select columns by subset and apply function `shift`:

```
cols = ['Col2','Col3']
df[cols] = df[cols].shift(1)
print (df)
       Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
Index                        
0        10   NaN   NaN    40
1        11  20.0  30.0    41
2        12  21.0  31.0    42
3        13  22.0  32.0    43
```

EDIT:

```
cols = ['Col2','Col3']
another_cols = df.columns.difference(cols)

df1 = df[another_cols].combine_first(df[cols].shift(1))
print (df1)
       Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
Index                        
0        10   NaN   NaN    40
1        11  20.0  30.0    41
2        12  21.0  31.0    42
3        13  22.0  32.0    43
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Is there a way to do it without "losing" the original df? Following your suggested way I practically overwrite the original df. The good thing about .shift() is that it has a "temporary" effect meaning that it does not overwrite the original df.

Comment: Yes, then is it a bit complicated - check editeda answer.